# How do I make one patch as a variable with pytorch's unfold method?

Tags: image-processing, pytorch, computer-vision

I divided an image of size `224 x 224` into patches and was able to change the pixel values of one patch with the following code snippet. Each patch is `16x16`,  so I have `196` patches all together.

```
uf = nnf.unfold(img, kernel_size=16, stride=16, padding=0)
uf[..., 130] = 0
f = nnf.fold(uf, img.shape[-2:], kernel_size=16, stride=16, padding=0)
```

`uf[..., 130] = 0` change all pixel values of the 130th patch to `0`. The above code simply splits the image into patches, edit the pixels of the specified patch and combine the patches back to form the complete image (the pixel manipulation is noticeable when visualized)

I need the patch as a variable. I expect `patch = uf[..., 130]` to give me a shape of `3x16x16` corresponding to the shape of the 130th patch but got `torch.Size([1, 768])` as the output.

How do I have one patch as a variable, get the correct output shape and be able to add the patch back to the fold method for combination?

Answer (score 0):

`unfold` returns a bidimensional matrix where the columns indicize each patch and the rows indicize the patch positions across the feature maps and the channels (indeed `768 == 3 * 16 * 16`).

If you just need the original shape back you can use `img.reshape(1, 3, 224, 224)`. You can also select the desired patch in the original image by converting 130 to double-index notation:

```py
h = ceil(224 / 16)
i, j = 130 // h, 130 % h
# indices to select the patch 130
idx, idy = range(i * 16, (i + 1) * 16), range(j * 16, (j + 1) * 16)
```

If you want to be sure to preserve gradients in the result you can use boolean masking, as follows:

```py
import torch
from math import ceil

img = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224, requires_grad=True)

h = ceil(224 / 16)
i, j = 130 // h, 130 % h

mask = torch.ones(224, 224)
mask[i * 16 : (i + 1) * 16, j * 16 : (j + 1) * 16] = 0

img = img * mask  # img.requires_grad is True
```

Comment: When I tried with preserving the gradient, I got an error: `IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 2`

Comment: Sorry I mistyped a command. `mask[i * 16 : (i + 1) * 16, j * 16 : (j + 1) * 16] = 0`. I'll fix it in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I now  see what your code is doing. I actually need to work on a patch and add it back to the image, not defining a mask

Comment: Then, this is dependent on the transformation you want to apply to the specific patch. Try to give a look at the `gather`, `scatter`, `masked_scatter` functions.

Comment: do you mean patch at (x, y) of the image by saying double-index notation? I would really love to do this. with a 224 x 224 image divided into patches of 16 x 16, i would have a 14 x 14 height and width. I'd like to just take the patch at (3, 5) by just doing image_patch(x, y), change the pixel values and merge them back to get the  complete image. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, with double-index notation I am converting the single index (130th patch) into a 2D indexing space (patch in position (x, y) or, better, (row, col)).

As for the remaining part, you can do `uf = nn.unfold(img, kernel_size=16, stride=16).squeeze(0).t().reshape(14, 14, 3, 16, 16)` and then you can select `uf[3, 5]`. Again, be careful to check whether your transformation preserves the gradient.